# Create shortcuts in Javascript for function names and properties?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm building a vanilla Javascript website (no jQuery), and I'm doing a lot of these things:

```
var e = document.getElementById(...);
e.addEventListener(...);
e.innerHTML = ...;
```

It works fine, but it's a lot of characters to type.

If there a simple way in Javascript to rename them to make them shorter? So I would be able to use something like this instead:

```
var e = getId(...);
e.on(...);
e.html = ...;
```

Comment: The generic way of creating "shortcuts" is to define functions. If you are not that familiar with functions, have a look at http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html .

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would probably be to define your own helper functions:

```
function getId(...args) {
  return document.getElementById(...args);
}

function on(e, ...args) {
  e.addEventListener(...args);
}

function html(e, value) {
  return e.innerHTML = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shure, however you need to have an eye on the context:

```
var getId=document.getElementById.bind(document);

Element.prototype.on=function(evt,handler){
 this.addEventListener(evt,handler);
 return this;
};

Element.prototype.html=function(set){
  if(set) return this.innerHTML=set;
  return this.innerHTML;
}

getId("el").on("click",function(){ alert(this.html());}).html("Hi!")
```

Note that *el.html=* requires a lot of work, thats why ive changed it to *el.html()* ... or not ( thanks to felix kling). One could also assign a getter/setter to the prototype:

```
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'html', {
  get: function() { return this.innerHTML;},
  set: function(value) { this.innerHTML = value; }
 }
);
```

Comment: Not *that* much work. `Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'html', {get: function() { return this.innerHTML;} set: function(value) { this.innerHTML = value; }});`